# Saving images of my IP-camera on my Desktop using FTP

Tags: ftp

I have a camera which allows FTP connections. If I want my camera to send an image to my Ubuntu Desktop, would I need to install an FTP server on my Desktop PC for this or is there an easier way?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [manual](http://www.hikvision.com/UploadFile/image/2013061411054615328.pdf) says that your screenshot shows settings for the cameras' FTP client, whichcan upload pictures to a FTP server.

In this case you need an FTP server on your desktop machine so the camera can connect to it and upload the images.

Comment: There is a checkbox: `Upload pictures` and I can specify a path in the cam-software. The IP-Adress is my Desktopcomputer. I see no way to push them on my Desktop though. It says it can't establish a connection.

Comment: I'm hesitant to have an FTP server on my machine (entry door for hackers). Any other way to get an updating picture (ideally at 25fps)?

Comment: We are talking about pictures here, you know, like "photos". Read the manual to find out how to access your camera.

Comment: As I understand the server opens port 21 on my Desktop PC, which seems risky too me. Accessing the camera is not the problem of my question.

Comment: The comment section is not for chatting, please open a new question if you want to ask something.